# Stop ViewController outside of navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development and have built a basic app to help familiarize myself with the conventions. It is a basic game with the following flow:

Main Menu -> (modal) New Game Type -> (Push Segue) Game -> (modal) Game over -> (Push Segue) Main Menu

My question deals with going from the Game/Game over back to the main menu. The menu is a ViewController, and the Game is a separate ViewController but NOT embedded in a navigation controller.

When I Push Segue BACK to the Main Menu after the game is over, what happens to the Game ViewController? Since it is not a modal, I can't dismiss it from the Main Menu ViewController, and when the user starts another game, does the Push Segue to the Game create another? Should I be stopping (and how) the finished Game ViewController?

I ask because when debugging, after running a few games I see a collection of  UITranitionView build up. I want to make sure I'm not leaking anything and handling the transitions correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone confused by this like I was, here is what I ended up doing.

As Ankit mentioned, a pop segue was the way to go, yet you can't POP a UIViewController off of a navigation stack that isn't there. So to fix that, I had to embed my Main View controller into a UINavigationController, then push both the game and game over vc's onto the navigation stack. Once the game was over, I did an unwind segue back to the Main vc.

Main Menu -> (Modal) New Game -> (PUSH) Game -> (PUSH)Game over -> (Unwind) Main

There is an option in interface builder to hide the navigation bar on a UINavigationController which is what I did.

Bottom Line: this flow I was using presupposed a navigation stack and thus required a UINavigationController. After realizing this things made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use proper transitions then use **"Main Menu -> (modal) New Game Type -> (Push Segue) Game -> (modal) Game over -> (POP Segue to main View Controller) Main Menu"** instead of using **"Main Menu -> (modal) New Game Type -> (Push Segue) Game -> (modal) Game over -> (Push Segue) Main Menu"**

Comment: My understanding is that the POP segue you describe works with ViewControllers that are embedded in Navigation Controllers, but NONE of my ViewControllers are. Should they be? Is this is the accepted practice?